# How to set up a JavaScript development infrastructure

Tags: javascript, git, npm

I'm working on a js framework that contains N modules.  Each module has its own github repository. 
ModuleA has a reference to ModuleB. It means that after each ModuleB update I have to do the following:

- commit changes to github repository and create a new release
- publish an updated package on npm
- run 'jspm install' for ModuleA and for all the other dependent modules.
- ....

It looks like a nightmare.

Could anybody suggest how to setup a development infrastructure to make this process easier? Maybe I need 'dev' version of 'package.json' file that is linked to local packages instead of npm/github or something like that? Please, suggest a proper way to do this.

Comment: Have you looked at `npm link`?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a workflow in the likes of:

1. Commit changes
2. Build server is notified and builds the project
3. If build succeeds, a release is created by the build server (see [Github API on releases](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#create-a-release))
4. If build succeeds, build server pushes npm package to npm hub

About the jspm install - you could probably make other builds that would be executed upon the first builds success. Those builds would clone the repo, run the jspm install/update command and then push to the repository..